# Исключение java.lang.NullPointerException. android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setTitle

Tags: java, android

Вызываю фрагмент в MainActivity:

```
loadFragment(ReadBookFragment.newInstance());

// Функция для загрузки фрагментов
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Код, где выскакивает ошибка(в ReadBookFragment):

```
@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
    pageNumber = page;
    getActivity().setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", "PDF Reader", page + 1, pageCount));
}
```

Сама ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.toprograms.bookstat.ReadBookFragment.onPageChanged(ReadBookFragment.java:110)
>           at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.showPage(PDFView.java:428)
>           at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.jumpTo(PDFView.java:397)
>           at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.loadComplete(PDFView.java:877)
>           at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DecodingAsyncTask.java:71)
>           at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Может кому-то пригодится. Я просто вместо
`loadFragment(ReadBookFragment.newInstance());`

написал:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_list_books);   

navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_read_book);

    public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // При перемещении по Bottom-бару switch определяет какой фрагмент показать на экране
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_list_books:
                loadFragment(ListBooksFragment.newInstance());
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_statistic:
                loadFragment(StatisticFragment.newInstance());
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_read_book:
                loadFragment(ReadBookFragment.newInstance());
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```